# Why are the contents of the subfolders when MQFTE is used for transfer?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, websphere-mq-fte

Hi when I tried to transfer the contents of a folder ( The folder has several subfolders and few files) using MQFTE ftecreatetransfer command, Not only the few files in the folder but also the contents of the subfolder are transferred to destination. The same subfolders are created in destination and the contents are transferred. Is there a way to avoid the files from subfolders being transferred ?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/start_new_transfer_cmd.htm) in the Infocenter:

> When a directory is specified as a source file specification, the
>   contents of the directory are copied. More precisely, all files in the
>   directory and in all its subdirectories, including hidden files, are
>   copied.

However, it looks like they anticipated your question because the page recently added this clarification:

> For example, to copy the contents of DIR1 to DIR2 only, specify
>   fteCreateTransfer ... -dd DIR2 DIR1/*

So instead of specifying the folder, add the wild card to the end and you get just the files in the top level of that folder. (Assuming of course that you do not also use the -r option!)

Comment: Hi Rob. Still facing the same problem. Instead of specifying the folder , i tried with the wild card to end. Could you please let me know in which version this is fixed.

Comment: It wasn't a fix in the product, they just updated the Infocenter to explain how the product already works. Can you update your question with the syntax of the `fteCreateTransfer` command you are using? The behavior you are describing sounds like the `-r` option is being used or it's not seeing the wildcard.

Comment: Rob could you please provide me the link in which the working is explained in infocenter ?

Comment: It's linked in my answer.  Will you be updating the question with the syntax of the commands you are trying?